# How to display the pdf on a browser?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, controller

I have a stream of bytes for a pdf file which I have stored in a session.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/start.htm")
    public String start(HttpServletRequest request, Model model)
            throws Exception 
{

// do something
request.getSession().setAttribute(uniqueId,bytesOfaPDF);

return "jspname";
}
```

Now I have put this in my JSP.

```
<object id="COB" data="/retrievePdf.htm" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%">

</object>
```

Now I have to write another method in my controller with the same mapping (`retrievePdf`) which will show PDF.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/retrievePdf.htm", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public void retrievePdf(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, ModelMap modelMap)throws OSOSystemException
    {
        byte[] db = (byte[]) request.getSession().getAttribute(uniqueId);

        response.getOutputStream().write(db);

        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
        response.setContentLength(db.length);


    }
```

But I am not able to understand how I can pass uniqueId to retrievePdf?

How I can achieve this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the unique ID as a query string in the URL

Store the unique id in request

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/start.htm")
    public String start(HttpServletRequest request, Model model)
            throws Exception 
{

// do something
// storing uniqueId
request.getSession().setAttribute("uniqueId",uniqueId) ;
request.getSession().setAttribute(uniqueId,bytesOfaPDF);

return "jspname";
}
```

In Jsp append the URL dynamicaally:

```
<% String uniqueId=request.getSession().getAttribute("uniqueId") ;
   String url = "/retrievePdf.htm?uniqueId="+uniqueId ;
%>

<object id="COB" data="<%=url%>" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%">

</object>
```

Add requestParam for uniqueId in the below method  and process it

```
@RequestMapping(value="/retrievePdf.htm", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public void retrievePdf(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, @RequestParam(value="uniqueId",required=true)String uniqueId,ModelMap modelMap)throws OSOSystemException
    {
        byte[] db = (byte[]) request.getSession().getAttribute(uniqueId);

        response.getOutputStream().write(db);

        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
        response.setContentLength(db.length);


    }
```

Thats all, it will work !!